# How to enable "Use Regular Expressions" option on the Find Widget in Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a way to programmatically select the "Use Regular Expressions" on the Find Widget in Monaco?

[image]

**UPDATE:** 
I was able to find a hacky solution by calling the `setRegex()` method on the `findWidget` but I would love to use only the public API:

```
var findWidget = this._editor.overlayWidgets['editor.contrib.findWidget'];
if (findWidget) {
    findWidget.widget._findInput.setRegex(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a method already:

```
controller = editor.getContribution('editor.contrib.findController');
controller.toggleRegex();
```

Answer was provided by @[brijeshb42](https://github.com/brijeshb42) in this issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/958#issuecomment-408069435